# Uppaal : Coffee Machine

Tags: uppaal

Hello I'm designing coffee vending machine problem in uppaal where customer orders **mocca** or **latte** upon inserting coin. The machine has to make sure that coin is inserted and there is enough water to atleast make **5** orders. If this condition is not fulfilled the coin has to be returned and **water level should fill to 5** for next order.
My design displays a deadlock after **customer 1** choses mocca.
The designs and error is there in this link [link to my designs](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xqi49qg3a0bu2e5/AACFilTSUSUaJEEC40ygDKaOa?dl=0)
The exercise is taken from this [Link](https://courses.cs.ttu.ee/w/images/b/b6/ITI0130_Lab1_Coffee_machine_2015.pdf)

Comment: What is your programming question for us?

Comment: how should I solve this deadlock ? and fulfil the main requirement.

Comment: @kali: could you please edit your question and provide inline source code for your problem?